# Animated model does not export as animated keyframes

Tags: animation, keyframes, .fbx, axis

I am animating an airplane model for a project. The model animations look fine the way I want in blender but when I export them as fbx or glb models the animation gets crazy. find the example as below:
[image]

The Animation I want
The animation that I am getting after export
[image]

blend file: [image]

Comment: Try changing your export settings axis. Also try applying rotation of your objects. (Ctrl+A)

Comment: @NascentSpace can you elaborate what you are trying to say I am relatively new to problems with animations in blender.

Comment: Usually when you export your model, a new window opens asking you where you want to place the new file. On the right, there will be options and parameters. Check somewhere for "Y up" or something related to that and change it

Comment: When you export an FBX a window opens with the export settings. If you go into the settings and find the armature section, you'll find the bone axis settings. You can set the bones' main axis and up axis. Try different settings and see if any works.

There are also settings for the scene up and forward axis. 

Different softwares use different axis as up and forward, and some even have the axis inverted, so it's usually a pain in the *** trying to export animations to other softwares (like game engines) until you find the correct settings (then you can save and name a preset)

Comment: Also I suspect there's a bug in latest blender versions that ignores the up and forward axis settings when exporting FBX, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I dug deep into the issue it seems something related to mesh skinning and Idk how to fix that.